# SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: in laravel

Tags: laravel, pdf-generation

**Error code :**

SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'works' (SQL: select * from `works` inner join `president_work` on `works`.`id` = `president_work`.`work_id` inner join `works` on `works`.`id` = `president_work`.`president_id` inner join `employee_work` on `president_work`.`work_id` = `employee_work`.`work_id` inner join `work_year` on `work_year`.`work_id` = `works`.`id` inner join `years` on `years`.`id` = `work_year`.`work_id` inner join `month_work` on `month_work`.`work_id` = `works`.`id` inner join `months` on `months`.`id` = `month_work`.`month_id`)

**Codes**

```
public function employeePDF()
    {
        $works = Work::join('president_work', 'works.id', '=', 'president_work.work_id')
            ->join('works', 'works.id', '=', 'president_work.president_id')
            ->join('employee_work', 'president_work.work_id', '=', 'employee_work.work_id')
            ->join('work_year', 'work_year.work_id', '=', 'works.id')
            ->join('years', 'years.id', '=', 'work_year.work_id')
            ->join('month_work', 'month_work.work_id', '=', 'works.id')
            ->join('months', 'months.id', '=', 'month_work.month_id')

            ->get();

        $pdf = PDF::loadView('work.pdf', ['works' => $works]);
        return $pdf->stream('report.pdf');
    }
```

Comment: Try this: `Work::join('president_work', 'works.id', '=', 'president_work.work_id')
            ->join('employee_work', 'president_work.work_id', '=', 'employee_work.work_id')
            ->join('work_year', 'work_year.work_id', '=', 'works.id')
            ->join('years', 'years.id', '=', 'work_year.work_id')
            ->join('month_work', 'month_work.work_id', '=', 'works.id')
            ->join('months', 'months.id', '=', 'month_work.month_id')
            ->get();`. You are joining works and president table twice. That might be the issue

Comment: Your `Work` model is calling your `works` table that you are joining with `works` table. Most likely you need to remove `->join('works', 'works.id', '=', 'president_work.president_id')`